# Querying data from Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Here's what my model structure looks like:

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Session(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    visit = models.ForeignKey(Visitor)
    sequence_no = models.IntegerField(null=False)

class Track(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    action = models.ForeignKey(Action)
    when = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)
    sequence_no = models.IntegerField(null = False)

class Action(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=65535, null=False)
    host = models.IntegerField(null=False)
```

As you can see, each `Visitor` has multiple `Sessions`; each `Session` has multiple `Tracks` and each `Track` has one `Action`. Tracks are always ordered ascendingly by the `session` and the `sequence_no`. A `Visitors` average time on an site (i.e. a particular `Action.host`) is the difference in `Track.when` (time) between the highest and lowest `Track.sequence_no` divided by the number of `Sessions` of that `Visitor`.

I need to calculate the average time of visitors on the site which be the sum of the time for each visitor on the `Action.site` divided by the number of visitors.

I could query this using SQL but I'd like to keep my query as Djangonic as possible and I'm still very lost with complex queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a specific `Action` object you can gather interesting data about Sessions:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Max
from yourapp.models import *

host = 1  # I suppose you want to calculate for each site

sessions = list(Session.objects.filter(
    track__action__host=host,
).annotate(
    start=Min('track__when'),
    end=Max('track__when'), 
).values('visit_id', 'start', 'end'))
```

You will get something in the line of:

```
[ 
  { 'visit_id': 1, 'start': datetime(...), 'end': datetime(...) },
  { 'visit_id': 1, 'start': datetime(...), 'end': datetime(...) },
  { 'visit_id': 2, 'start': datetime(...), 'end': datetime(...) },
 ....
]
```

Now it's only a matter of getting the desired result from the data:

```
number_of_visitors = len(set(s['visit_id'] for s in sessions))
total_time = sum((s['end'] - s['start']).total_seconds() for s in sessions)
average_time_spent = total_time / number_of_visitors
```

Another way is to use two queries instead of one, and avoid the `len(set(...))` snippet:

```
sessions = Session.objects.filter(
    track__action__host=host,
).annotate(
    start=Min('track__when'),
    end=Max('track__when'), 
)

number_of_visitors = sessions.values('visit_id').distict().count()
total_time = sum((s['end'] - s['start']).total_seconds() 
    for s in sessions.values('start', 'end'))
```

There is NO WAY to do actual calculated fields barring the provided aggregations, so either you do it in raw SQL or you do in code like this.

At least the proposed solution uses Django's ORM as far as possible.