# Average calculated on the difference on a Min and Max value in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have two simple tables in Django which looks like:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Track(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session)
    when = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to find a the average duration of all the sessions. The duration of a session is calculated by subtracting the highest `when` value with the lowest `when` value. Can I do something like this:

```
Session.objects.all().annotate(duration=Max('track__when') - Min('track__when')).aggregate(Avg('duration'))
```

Any better methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already answered you the same question in [Querying data from Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954746/help-with-querying-data-from-django) , you can't do using only the ORM API, either:

1. you extend the API by defining your custom annotations, or
2. you do part of the algorithm in python, in your view/templatetag/whatever